# Local arrays in zsh

Tags: arrays, zsh, local-variables

Zsh has two nice features, the `local` keyword and the arrays concept.

```
local my_var # Declare variable local to this function
```

and

```
arr=(1 2 3) # Create array with 3 elements
arr+=4 # Add a fourth element
```

respectively.

The idea to combine them (`local arr=()`) is irresistible, but seems to just give an error? Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least the situation in [1999](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/1999/msg00011.html) was that it's not possible on a single line, but this work around exists:

```
local arr
arr=()
```

Credits should go to Peter Stephenson for answering this back then.

Answer (score 6):

Of course, now you can do:

```bash
local -a arr
```

Comment: "Now"? Is this a new thing?

Comment: Probably not, but I don't know when (if ever) it was first introduced. AFAIK `local` has always been a wrapper for `typeset` so I suppose it's been legit as long as arrays have been in `zsh.

Comment: I find this answer to be incorrect. `local -a arr=(1 2 3)` still yields `zsh: unknown file attribute`. Remember, I wanted to set a *new* and *local* variable to an array value.

Comment: @Tarrasch direct initilisation doesn't work indeed, but then arr really behave like an array. just do `local -a arr;arr=(1 2 3)` instead